# Karate param on multi scenario

Tags: karate

My api looks like api.com/first/second

My script is calling login.feature, to get a token and karate-config.js for the headers like (X-CustomCode : "1", 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')

Request looks like: api.com/first/second/token=number

workflow.feature looks like:

```
Feature: Work

Background:
    * def result = call read('login.feature')
    * param token = result.token
```

Everything works, when the scenario is like:

```
Scenario: Get to work
    Given path '/first/second/'
    When method get
    Then status 200
```

But when there are multi requests in the scenario, it seems that param is not picked up, resulting in missing .../token=number. Headers are set correctly in the request, but the token is missing.

Comment: maybe it is a bug in karate so please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue - and make sure you upgrade first

Comment: "params are not re-used across http calls" was the key here :)

Comment: ah thanks, (you are one of the good ones) - thanks for the update !